# What's wrong in this SQL Query with NOT LIKE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM combinazioni
WHERE (
    sesso = '3'
    OR sesso = 'f'
)
AND (
    menopausa = '3'
    OR menopausa = '1'
)
AND (
    ipert_a = '3'
    OR ipert_a = '1'
)
AND (
    obesita = '3'
    OR obesita = '1'
)
AND (
    LOWER( i_alimento ) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER( ii_alimento ) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER( iii_alimento ) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER( iv_alimento ) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER( v_alimento ) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%'
)
ORDER BY rilevanza_1 DESC
```

I don't understand the problem. Why doesn't this query work?
I try to execute this code in PHPMyAdmin but it does not give me the record that I want. The query does not give any errors but returns records with "ricotta".

I want that this query show me the records that *don't* have "ricotta" in any of the `i_alimento`, `ii_alimento`, `iii_alimento`, `iv_alimento`, `v_alimento` fields.

Comment: You need to explain this sentence *this query not work*.  You can add sample data and what your current query is returning and what you are expecting

Comment: Is it showing you records that have "riccota" in one of the elements ?  Or does it not show you records that don't ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you want `and` instead of `or`.  But, you should use `in` and simplify the whole `where` clause:

```
WHERE sesso IN ('3', 'F') AND
      menopausa IN ('1', '3') AND
      ipert_a IN ('1', '3') AND
      obesita IN ('1', '3') AND
      (LOWER(i_alimento) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%' AND
       LOWER(ii_alimento) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%' AND
       LOWER(iii_alimento) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%' AND
       LOWER(iv_alimento) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%' AND
       LOWER(v_alimento) NOT LIKE '%ricotta%'
      )
```

This checks that 'ricotta' does not appear for *any* of the five "alimento"s.  If you use `or`, then it just checks that at most one of them doesn't contain `'ricotta'`.

Also, if you decide that you really do want `OR`, you should have parentheses around the conditions.

Comment: thanks a lot gordon. the word "ricotta" does not have to be contained in all four fields. all you need is a field that has "ricotta" inside

Comment: i continue to have the problem. your solution not work.

Comment: @MatteoRenzi do you want to select all the records that contain 'ricotta' in all the columns that you have mentioned with other conditions as well ?

Comment: @Suraz i want to select all the records that NOT contain 'ricotta' in one of the fields. 'ricotta' not must be in one of the fields.

Comment: @MatteoRenzi . . . Mateo, if "not in one of the fields" means "not in *any* of the fields", then use `AND`.  If "not in one of the fields" means "not in *all* of the fields", then use `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query,

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM combinazioni
    WHERE 
    sesso =  '3' OR sesso =  'f'
    AND 
    menopausa =  '3' OR menopausa =  '1'
    AND 
    ipert_a =  '3' OR ipert_a =  '1'
    AND 
    obesita =  '3' OR obesita =  '1'
    AND 
    LOWER(i_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(ii_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(iii_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(iv_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(v_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    ORDER BY rilevanza_1 DESC ;
```

You can also use IN function which provides perfect result.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM combinazioni
    WHERE 
    sesso in ('3','f') AND 
    menopausa in ('3','1') AND 
    ipert_a in ('3','1') AND 
    obesita in ('3','1') AND 
    LOWER(i_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(ii_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(iii_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(iv_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    OR LOWER(v_alimento) NOT LIKE  '%ricotta%'
    ORDER BY rilevanza_1 DESC ;
```

Hope it is useful to you. Any issues let me know will help you.

Comment: i want to select all the records that NOT contain 'ricotta' in one of the fields. your help still not work.

Comment: Will you be able to provide how your data looks like? Will be very much helpful to provide you a solution

Comment: the solution is write AND where i've write OR like the @Gordon Linoff 's solution. thanks a lot.

Comment: Thats fine. Please vote if you feel its really helpful